# Wine Bad EXE Error

Tags: wine, itunes

so I'm trying to install iTunes through wine, and whenever I use the terminal command `wine iTunes6464setup.exe` to run itunes, it tells me that it's a `bad EXE file`. I'm not sure how to fix it, and the other questions didn't contain what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Wine App Database entry for iTunes: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31322

I see that people have needed to download the special version of iTunes "for older video cards" from Apple, because the regular one doesn't install. (My guess is this is to avoid piracy of paid video content through HDMI output, though I don't know for sure.) Here's the download link: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1816?locale=en_US

There are more notes and information at the WineHQ site. It indicates that you may need to also install "gdiplus" through winetricks or playonlinux before iTunes 12 will work.

Comment: alright, thanks. I'll try this solution out and let you know what happens.

Comment: Hey, thanks! It worked perfectly. iTunes is running just fine and I've got my imported playlist to work.

Comment: Haha. Just kidding. It's run into an error that won't let it run at all. The error report also won't load, so I'm not sure why it isn't working. I'll keep trying and see what the error is.

Comment: Forgot to add, the "gdiplus" isn't working. I wasn't entirely sure where to locate it, and it never "installed," only "unzipped."

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, I believe gdiplus is installable through winetricks https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks , and its installer is integrated into playonlinux. There's probably a way to download and install it manually, too, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: I tried it through winetricks and it didn't seem to work. Maybe I did something wrong. But I got itunes 10 to work just fine, so I'll confirm that that route works just fine.